# Finding the frequency of words (Perl)

Tags: perl, word-frequency

I am trying to find the frequency of words in a user file. I have it to where it finds the numbers of words, lines, and characters, but I am a little stuck on finding the frequency of the words.

This is what I have. I know that I need to need to make a hash table and store the words in the hash table accordingly. But, I am a little stuck on getting the output correct. It printing out a bunch of gibberish right now.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;


open(FILE, "<test.txt") or die "Could not open file: $!";

my ($lines, $words, $chars) = (0,0,0);
my %count;

while (<FILE>) {


    $lines++;
    $chars += length($_);
    $words += scalar(split(/\s+/, $_));
    $count{$words}++;


}

print("Number of characters: $chars\n");
print("Number of words: $words\n");
print("Number of lines: $lines\n");

foreach $words (sort keys %count) {
        print("$words, $count{$words}\n");
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `scalar(split(...))` forces the result of the `split` (an array of words) into scalar context (giving the length of the array) - this is not what you want. You should be looping over the array of words and incrementing the count in the hash for each word.

Comment: I believe I see what you mean. I am going to try something new out real quick and update if it goes. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: no, array is a variable type, not a type of value; split "Splits the string EXPR into a list of strings and returns the list in list context, or the size of the list in scalar context." there is no array there.

Comment: True, I was incorrect in my wording - an array never gets produced when `split` is called in scalar context. The result is the same, though.

Comment: Any reason you need to do it in PERL? Using command line 'wc --chars test.txt', 'wc --words test.txt', 'wc --lines test.txt' will do the job for you, and you can invoke them from PERL via system(). And for the most frequent word 'sed -e 's/\s/\n/g' < test.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head  -1'

Comment: @runrouni88 I am just trying to learn something new. I have used C++ a lot and a bit of java. I am just trying to learn a different language. I appreciate the knowledge with command line and sed though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have quickly gone over the code.

I believe this is what you want, it is untested. Still, it should give you some pointers.

I have added some comments to give a hint as to what I think went wrong in your code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;

use strict;


open(FILE, "<test.txt") or die "Could not open file: $!";

my ($lines, $words, $chars) = (0,0,0);

my %count;

while (my $line = <FILE>) {

$lines++;

# $chars += length($_); problem: also counts whitespaces. Probably not intended.
my $nr_of_chars =()= $line =~ /[a-z]/gi; #counts characters only
$chars += $nr_of_chars;

my @words = split(/\s+/, $line );

for my $word ( @words ){
$count{$word}++;
}

# $words += scalar ( split(/\s+/, $_ )); <- counts words, adds to $words
# $count{$words}++ <- this sets, for example, $count{7}++ if there were 7 in $words.
# that is quite certainly not helpful. You are not actually storing the word anywhere

$words += scalar( @words );
}

print("Number of characters: $chars\n");

print("Number of words: $words\n");

print("Number of lines: $lines\n");

foreach $word ( keys %count) {
    print("$word, ".$count{$word}."\n"); # print "$count{$word" does not work
}
```

Comment: "# $count{$words}++ <- this sets, for example, $count{7}++ if there were 7 in $words."

This makes so much more sense now! Thank you! My output was constantly 6. My test file, only had 6 words in it. So, that is why it was constantly outputting 6. I understood what @Andrew Medico meant by looping over the arrays. I have just been trying to implement that the whole time and I was fairly close. I just do not fully grasp some things about Perl yet. Thank you again for your time and help!